# Как определить propTypes для функционального компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я попытался сделать так:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import './Button.scss'

export default function Button(props) {
    return (
        <div className="button">
            <button>{props.name}</button>
        </div>
    )
}

Button.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string
}
```

Однако, использование в другом модуле `<Button name={[1, 2, 3]} />` не вызывает никаких ошибок при сборке. Следовательно, либо я не полностью понимаю, как работает `propTypes`, либо я просто неправильно его применяю к компоненту.

Я также пробовал писать внутри компонента `this.propTypes=...` однако из-за этого почему-то вообще все компоненты отвалились и перестали отображаться в браузере. И никакой ошибки сборки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в том что Вы экспортируете до то того как будет применен `PropTypes`, попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import "./Button.scss"

function Button(props) {
    return (
        <div className="button">
            <button>{props.name}</button>
        </div>
    )
}

Button.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string
}

export default Button
```

UPDATE:

Убедитесь что Вы проверяете `props` с помощью `PropTypes` в компоненте в который Вы их передаете, а выполняете проверку находясь в компоненте из которого вы их передаете.

Comment: На самом деле, ничего не изменилось. Он всё ещё пропускает массивы в props.name

Comment: Нет, на самом деле, вы правы. Просто я ожидал ошибку сборки, а на деле этот модуль флудит ошибками в консоль браузера.